# What is on the "x-axis" of an plot from a Gaussian Process

Tags: regression, gaussian, feature-detection

I try the understand how the Gaussian Process works. So if I'm sampling from it, I will get values, which come from a multivariate distribution.

Let's say I have 5 input features in my training data. So one training point is a 5d vektor like: [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]. Each training point has a 1d target value.

After inferring the posterior distribution and plotting samples from the GP,  what actually is on the y-axis and what is on the X-axis?

Am I right that the y-value, so actually the function value, is my target ?
Is it right that on the x-axis there are indices, which stand for one training point, so here: [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5]?

Thanks!

Comment: Not a programming question - try https://stats.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is posted in the wrong stackexchange community, should go to stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - Yep, you're absolutely correct.

Typically, when visualizing a Gaussian Process (GP):

- the x-axis is the index position i.e. this will match the length of your vectors
- the y-axis is the value

If you sample 10 times from a 5-dimensional multivariate GP this gives you:

```
[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5],
[b1, b2, b3, b4, b5],
[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5],
[d1, d2, d3, d4, d5],
[e1, e2, e3, e4, e5],
[f1, f2, f3, f4, f5],
[g1, g2, g3, g4, g5],
[h1, h2, h3, h4, h5],
[i1, i2, i3, i4, i5],
[j1, j2, j3, j4, j5]
```

Each sample vector (e.g. `[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5]`) is represented by a single line consisting of the 5 coordinates

[image: Samples from a 5-dimensional Gaussian Process].

Note: The plot has been created using python which starts its indexing from 0 so for a 5-dimensional vector, the index positions are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4